# Как привязать функции в PySide6 к клавишам с использованием Shortcut?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, pyside6

Я прочитал документацию по `Shortcut`, но не понял как привязать событие. Может я что-то упустил.

Ниже фрагмент кода - это моя попытка сделать что-то похожее на пример в документации:

```
swapPanelShortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(
    QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.Qt.CTRL + QtGui.Qt.Key_U),
    self.btnChangePanel
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `QShortcut` используется для создания сочетаний клавиш.

Класс `QKeySequence` инкапсулирует последовательность клавиш,
используемую shortcuts.

> void QShortcut::**activated**()  [signal]
>
> Этот сигнал испускается, когда пользователь набирает последовательность
> клавиш быстрого доступа.

Установите импорты для **`PySide6`** и попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QShortcut, \
    QLabel, QHBoxLayout
    
 
class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.label = QLabel(
            'Press `Ctrl + O` \n или \nPress `Ctrl + Q`'
            '\n или \nPress `Ctrl + U`'
            , self)
 
        self.shortcut_open = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+O'), self)
        self.shortcut_open.activated.connect(self.on_open)
        
        self.shortcut_update = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+U'), self)
        self.shortcut_update.activated.connect(self.on_update)
 
        self.shortcut_close = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+Q'), self)
        self.shortcut_close.activated.connect(self.closeApp)    
 
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
 
    def on_open(self):
        print('Вы нажали: `Ctrl+O`')
        
    def on_update(self):
        print('Вы нажали: `Ctrl+U`')
 
    def closeApp(self):
        app.quit()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AppDemo()
    w.resize(200, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!